# Create stored procedure with updating multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I am getting the following error in my code:

> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 20

```
CREATE PROCEDURE updateUser(
    IN firstname VARCHAR(20), 
    IN Vlastname VARCHAR(20), 
    IN Vemail VARCHAR(50), 
    IN Vpassword VARCHAR(100), 
    IN Vyear INT(5), 
    IN Vgender VARCHAR(10), 
    IN Vprefer VARCHAR(200), 
    IN Vinterested VARCHAR(200), 
    IN Vabout VARCHAR(200), 
    IN Vid INT(11)
) 
BEGIN
    UPDATE users SET 
        name = (CASE WHEN firstname IS NOT NULL THEN firstname ELSE name
            END),
        lastname = (CASE WHEN vlastname IS NOT NULL THEN vlastname ELSE lastname
            END)
WHERE id = Vid
END;
```

Comment: Simplify: `name = coalesce(firstname, name)`.

Comment: Perhaps a missing semicolon after the UPDATE statement?

Comment: not working it still has an error:#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When developing stored procedures in MySQL, you must set a delimiter different from `;` to properly end the stored program statement. This allows the use of `;` to delineate multiple statements within the procedure.

Per MySQL 25.1 Defining Stored Programs [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html):

> If you use the `mysql` client program to define a stored program containing semicolon characters, a problem arises. By default, `mysql` itself recognizes the semicolon as a statement delimiter, so you must redefine the delimiter temporarily to cause `mysql` to pass the entire stored program definition to the server.

Therefore consider below adjustment:

```sql
DELIMITER //                        -- TEMPORARILY CHANGE DELIMITER FROM ;

CREATE PROCEDURE updateUser (
    IN firstname VARCHAR(20), 
    IN Vlastname VARCHAR(20), 
    IN Vemail VARCHAR(50), 
    IN Vpassword VARCHAR(100), 
    IN Vyear INT(5), 
    IN Vgender VARCHAR(10), 
    IN Vprefer VARCHAR(200), 
    IN Vinterested VARCHAR(200), 
    IN Vabout VARCHAR(200), 
    IN Vid INT(11)
) 
BEGIN
    UPDATE `users` 
    SET 
        `name` = CASE WHEN `firstname` IS NOT NULL THEN `firstname` ELSE `name` END,
        `lastname` = CASE WHEN `vlastname` IS NOT NULL THEN `vlastname` ELSE `lastname` END
     WHERE `id` = Vid;              -- SEMICOLON HERE TO SEPARATE STATEMENTS
END
//                                  -- PROPERLY END PROCEDURE STATEMENT

DELIMITER ;                         -- RESET DELIMITER BACK TO ;
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a semicolon after The `WHERE` clause
And you can simplify it

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE updateUser(
    IN firstname VARCHAR(20), 
    IN Vlastname VARCHAR(20), 
    IN Vemail VARCHAR(50), 
    IN Vpassword VARCHAR(100), 
    IN Vyear INT(5), 
    IN Vgender VARCHAR(10), 
    IN Vprefer VARCHAR(200), 
    IN Vinterested VARCHAR(200), 
    IN Vabout VARCHAR(200), 
    IN Vid INT(11)
) 
BEGIN
    UPDATE users SET 
        name = COALESCE (firstname, name),
        lastname = COALESCE (vlastname,lastname)
    WHERE id = Vid;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```